# Material Button Toggle Group not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-togglebutton

I am trying to use [Material toggle group](https://material.io/components/buttons/android#toggle-button) in an existing application.

I found that it works (visible) only when the application is using Material components theme.

Since the existing application is using Theme.AppCompat.Light and I cannot change the application theme to Material components.

I tried to use "ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents" for toggle group but it doesn't work.

Also I didn't found much documentation regarding themes and overlay themes.

**(edit) code preview[image]**

After changing the theme to Material components either in design tool bar or in the styles.xml. [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot change your theme to inherit from a Material Components theme, you can inherit from a Material Components **Bridge** theme which inherits from AppCompat themes, but also define the new Material Components theme attributes:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.Bridge">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/.....</item>
    <!-- ... -->
    
</style>
```

Comment: @mohammedahmedahmed what does it mean "isn't working" ?

Comment: After I change the parent of application theme to "Material Components Bridge", the toggle group is still not visible.

Comment: @mohammedahmedahmed just tried with 1.3.0 without any issue

Comment: I am using 1.3.0 as well. I created a quick application and added snapshot of code.